# Why is this conditional statement not working in C?

Tags: c, loops, linked-list

I'm trying to create a program in C that is able to create a list of characters (using a linked list) input by the user, and follow these commands: insert (adds a new character to the list), remove (clears the list and deletes all elements), print (prints the current contents of the list) and exit (closes the program). In order for it to work, the user must enter the command to execute first. For instance, if they type 'insert', they will be prompted to enter a character, if they type 'print', the program will print the list, and so on.

To approach this, I basically declared a `char[]` variable called `command`. Which represents the user's text input. After receiving the input, the program will compare the `command` string to the following strings: `insert`, `remove`, `print`, and `exit`, and if the strings match, then the program will execute the command that the string corresponds to (refer to the `main` below):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct linked_list 
{
    char data;
    struct linked_list* next;
};

void insert(struct linked_list** head, char input);
void removed(struct linked_list** head);
void printed(struct linked_list* head);

void insert(struct linked_list** head, char input) {
    int x;
    x = ("%d",input);
    if (x < 97 || x > 122) {
        printf("The character you entered is invalid, please use the insert command and try again\n");
    } 
    else {
        struct linked_list* newNode = (struct linked_list*) malloc(sizeof(struct linked_list));
        struct linked_list* lastNode = *head;
        newNode->data = input;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        if (*head == NULL) {
            *head = newNode;
            return;
        }
        while (lastNode->next != NULL) {
            lastNode = lastNode->next;
        }
        lastNode->next = newNode;
    }       
}

void removed(struct linked_list** head) {
    struct linked_list* current = *head;
    struct linked_list* next;
    
    while(current != NULL) {
        next = current->next;
        free(current);
        current = next;
    }
    *head = NULL;
}

void printed(struct linked_list* head) {
    while (head != NULL) {
        printf("%c ", head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char command[] = "";
    char inserts[] = "insert";
    char removes[] = "remove";
    char prints[] = "print";
    char exits[] = "exit";
    char input;
    struct linked_list* head = NULL;
    int done = 1; //Variable used to keep the loop going until the user types 'exit'
    printf("Welcome, please use the commands 'insert', 'remove', 'print' or 'exit' to use the program\n");
    while (done == 1) {
        scanf("%s", &command);
        int result1 = strcmp(command,inserts);
        int result2 = strcmp(command,removes);
        int result3 = strcmp(command,prints);
        int result4 = strcmp(command,exits);
        
        if (result1 == 0) {
            printf("Enter a char: ");
            scanf("%s", &input);
            insert(&head, input);
            result1 = 1;        
        }
        else if (result2 == 0) {
            removed(&head);
            result2 = 1;
        }
        else if (result3 == 0) {
            printed(head);
            result3 = 1;
        }
        else if (result4 == 0) {
            printf("The program will close now");
            done = 0;
        }
        else {
            printf("Unrecognized command, please try again\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The solution I came up with works perfectly for the commands `insert`, `remove`, and `print`. However, for some reason I can't quite understand it doesn't work for `exit`, it will only work if and only if exit is the first command you enter (which doesn't make sense, since why would you exit a program without even using it). There are no typos or other apparent errors. You can compile the code and see for yourself. What might be causing this issue? Why does it work for three of the command words but not for one?
Thanks in advance

UPDATE: After messing around with the code a little bit, I realized none of the suggestions provided were the issue. I simply changed my loop statement to be : `else if (strcmp(command,"exit")==0)` and it worked perfectly

Comment: You must have missed something from the early beginners chapters of your C book. What do you think `x = ("%d",input);` will do?

Comment: Don't hard code values like `97` and `122`.  If you are using `97` because you expect that to be the integer value of the letter `'a'` in the character set, then you should write `'a'`.  This makes it easier for the reader to know what the code is doing, and will continue to work if the character set changes.

Comment: Furthermore, `char command[] = "";` creates an array of a single element, and initializes it to the string null terminator. Even a one-character string will go out of bounds of the array.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's the "string literal annotated assignment" idiom.

Comment: @WilliamPursell That's not really enough, since there are encodings in current use (though not common I'll admit) where letters are not consecutively numbered. `islower` (or `isalpha`) would be better for this case

Comment: All in all, I'd recommend you take a few steps back and get a decent beginners book and start from the first chapter.

Comment: What I was trying to with the  `("%d",input);` was to take the integer value of the character the user inputs based on the ASCII table. (For example a would equal 97). What's the correct way to do this then?

Comment: Notice that StackOverflow is *not* a do-my-homework website. Your teacher expects you to spend time in learning things.

Comment: I think none of you really executed this code. None of the answers I've received so far have been useful to the problem in question. All the functions are fine, even the `("%d",input);` part works as intended, so I don't get why people are suggesting that I don't know about C programming. Also, this is not really "doing my homework", Mr. Basile Starynkevitch, because so far the program is 95% complete, and I came up with it all by myself.

Comment: Just to start... fix the warnings here: https://godbolt.org/z/5of3hs

Comment: Note that: `<source>:69:21: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[1]' [-Wformat]
        scanf("%s", &command);` is quite serious and results in undefined behavior...

Comment: Two of those warnings come from the declaration of the main method (which is the same for every program really). The first one I did correct, but it wasn't really breaking my program, and the one you're specifically talking about, I tried using the original `scanf("%c", &command);`, but if you use `%c` the program will just scan the first letter of the command, so if you type `insert` it will only read it as an `i`.

Comment: Be sure to test your program with various inputs, including long lines (of e.g. 200 letters), and strange strings like `СТАРЫНКЕВИЧ` made of Cyrillic letters UTF-8 encoded. Regarding the 95% complete figure, you are optimistic.

Answer (score 4):

```
x = ("%d",input);
```

involves the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). The left operand `"%d"` is evaluated (to itself, since a literal string, then discarded) and the right operand `input` is evaluated and result of that comma operator.

So `x` becomes `input`

You may want to spend a dozen of minutes reading about [scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) or about [getchar](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar). It can fail. You should handle both failure and success (with some test).

My personal recommendation : **enable all warnings and debug info in your compiler**. With [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Improve your code to get no warnings. Then **use your debugger** (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)) **to understand the behavior of your program**.

Of course you will spend some time reading the documentation of your compiler and of your debugger.

Don't forget to spend some time reading [a good book](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) on the C programming language. Refer also to [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). Study also for inspiration the source code of existing [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) (like [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)) coded in C. You will learn a lot by reading *existing* [reviewed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_review) C code.

You may also want to read something about [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques. You could consider (if your teacher allows that) using parser generators like [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) (which *generates* C code).

Be aware that in 2021 [UTF-8 is used everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/).

### Be scared and avoid [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In some cases, a program appears to work, but does not. Read some C standard (like [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) explaining it. I guess your program has several [buffer overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).

You could also (if your teacher allows it) use tools like the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/), [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) or the [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer)

Comment: What I was trying to do there was to take the integer value of the character the user inputs based on the ASCII table. (For example a would equal 97). What's the correct way to do this then?

Comment: Also, x becoming input is precisely what I need for the program to run, so there's no mistake there

Comment: There are *many* mistakes in your code, but you need time ([years](http://www.norvig.com/21-days.html), not hours) to learn programming. I wish you have fun in [debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging) your program. You need at least several weeks of work

Comment: Have fun in debugging your code. **You should use your debugger.** I see approximately a mistake every two or three lines, and you will discover more of them.

Comment: @NicolásOrtíz - there are errors in your program.  C is not forgiving when it comes to incorrect string manipulation.  There is a reason why security oriented developers hate C.  There is also a reason everyone is telling you to look at warnings as this will help you to learn why and where things went wrong and how to fix them.

Comment: @NicolásOrtíz " nor there are logic errors." --> With `char command[] = "";  scanf("%s", &command);` --> Oh yes, there are indeed errors.  Cursory review and at least a a few more outright errors and various weaknesses.  Enable all warnings to get the easy ones.

Comment: @NicolásOrtíz There are *huge* errors in your program.  You are pretty much guaranteed to invoke undefined behavior very early in the execution.  To ignore the advice that people are giving you and chastise them for not running your code is not the correct response.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your commands aren't working as intended is that you declare zero-length string literal:

```
char command[] = "";
```

then read user input into it:

```
scanf("%s", &command);
```

The user input isn't going to fit into zero characters, so it's going to overwrite something else in memory, likely something important.

You need to declare an actual buffer that's large enough to hold the largest expected input, something like this:

```
char command[10];
```

You also need to clear or initialize that buffer, perhaps using `memset(command, 0, sizeof(command));`

Something similar happens with `input`. It's declared as `char` but then you read a string (`%s`) into it:

```
scanf("%s", &input);
```

Even if you only type one character, `scanf` still has to store a terminating NUL, so it will clobber something else in memory.

With all these buffer overwrites going on, what the program actually does, and why exit only works as the first command, is anybody's guess.

Comment: Why do you need to memset the buffer? The program is reading into it.

Comment: Because `scanf` can fail. Then the buffer stays uninitialized, and undefined behavior is likely

Comment: Actually that's not an issue, because I had the `char command[] = " ";` before and it didn't mess things up with the other commands. Sure, it might not be the best programming habit, but it wasn't the real cause of the issue, which I already found

Comment: @NicolásOrtíz Some of the comments on this question are gratuitous, like the ones about handling UTF-8 input; this is obviously a linked list exercise and not a character encoding exercise. But you should pay attention to the people who point out issues like buffer overruns and expressions that don't make any sense. Presumably you want to be able to write computer programs, right? You're not going to be able to do that if you think that reading a 5-character string into a 1-character buffer is going to work. It may work by coincidence now, but it won't the next time, and you won't know why.